# Explain me how does this Shell pipe magic (... | tee >(tail -c1 >$PULSE) | bzip2 | ...) works?

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, pipe, io-redirection

Here the [original source code](https://github.com/starkandwayne/shield/blob/v0.10.9/bin/shield-pipe#L88-L117) (relevant 30 lines `bash` code highlighted)

Here simplified (`s3` is a binary which streams to object storage). The dots (...) are options not posted here.

```
PULSE=$(mktemp -t shield-pipe.XXXXX)
trap "rm -f ${PULSE}" QUIT TERM INT

set -o pipefail
mysqldump ... | tee >(tail -c1 >$PULSE) | bzip2 | s3 stream ...
```

How does that work exactly? Can you explain me how this redirections and pipes working? Howto debug the error `mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write`. When manually invoked (only) `mysqldump`  never fails with an error.

Comment: The error 32 corresponds to broken pipe. Looks like `bzip2` finished thereby closing one end of the pipe for reading, but `mysqldump` kept writing data to the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is that:

- `tee` writes to standard output as well as a file
- `>( cmd )` creates a writeable process substitution (a command that mimics the behaviour of a writeable file)

This is used to effectively pipe the output of `mysqldump` into two other commands: `tail -c1` to print the last byte to a file and `bzip2` to compress the stream.

As Inian pointed out in the comments, the error 32 comes from a broken pipe. I guess that this comes from `s3 stream` terminating (maybe a timeout?) which in turn causes the preceding commands in the pipeline to fail.